# Funciones set y get dinámicas para clases mediante herencia en php

Tags: php, poo, scope

Estoy intentando crear una clase base con métodos en común para luego extender todas mis clases y evitar repetir métodos. De momento llevo un método de llenado y otro de obtención de las propiedades de la clase.

Estas funciones también permiten manipular los valores antes de asignar/obtener el respectivo valor (*Algo así como lo hace laravel con accesors y mutators*).

El problema está en que solo funciona cuando las propiedades de la clase hijo son publicas y no privadas o protegidas. Esto es así ya que en una clase normal no se puede asegurar que la propiedad exista en la clase hijo y por eso no puede generar una dependencia.

He intentado con una `clase abstracta`, pero dado que quiero mis propiedades de las respectivas clases serán dinámicas no es lo que ando buscando.

Finalmente intenté con un `trait`, pero el comportamiento es el mismo que con una clase "normal".

¿Hay alguna alternativa para poder acceder a las propiedades de las clases hijos desde los padres?

```
<?php 
class model{
  protected $classname;
  protected $fillable;
  protected $obtainable;
  const MUTATOR_FUNCTION_PREFIX = "set_";
  const ACCESOR_FUNCTION_PREFIX = "get_";

  function __construct(){
    $this->fillable = [];
    $this->obtainable = [];
  }

  public function fill($params){
    if(gettype($params) != 'array'){
      return null;
    }
    foreach($this->fillable as $property){
      $property_exist = isset($params[$property]); 
      if($property_exist){
        $method = self::MUTATOR_FUNCTION_PREFIX . $property; 
        if(method_exists($this->classname, $method)){
          $this->$property = $this->classname::$method($params[$property]);
        }else{
          $this->$property = $params[$property];
        }
      }
    }
  }

  public function get(){
    $response = new stdClass();
    foreach($this->obtainable as $property){
      $property_exist = isset($this->$property); 
      if($property_exist){
        $method = self::ACCESOR_FUNCTION_PREFIX . $property; 
        if(method_exists($this->classname, $method)){
          $response->$property = $this->classname::$method($this->$property);
        }else{
          $response->$property = $this->$property;
        }
      }
    }
    return $response;
  }
}

class publication extends model {
    public $comment;
    function __construct(){
        $this->fillable = ['comment'];
        $this->obtainable = ['comment'];
    }
}

$publication = new publication();
$publication->fill(["comment" => "This is my first comment"]);
print_r($publication->get());
```

Comment: El problema que le veo es que este tipo de diseño es que te puede provocar problemas en el futuro, ya que si por alguna razón se define en la clase padre una propiedad que se utiliza en una clase hija... ¿cual debería ser asignada/obtenida realmente por los métodos de la clase padre?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En respuesta a:

> El problema está en que solo funciona cuando las propiedades de la clase hijo son publicas y no privadas o protegidas.

Es cierto solo en el caso de que las propiedades de la clase *"hija"* sean privadas (`private`), pero si las propiedades son publicas (`public`) o protegidas (`protected`) entonces estas si pueden ser accedidas desde la clase *"padre"* sin ningún problema.

[Manual PHP > Clases y objetos > Visibilidad](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.visibility.php)

> [...] A los miembros de clase declarados como '**public**' se puede acceder desde donde sea; a los miembros declarados como '**protected**', solo desde la misma clase o mediante clases heredadas. A los miembros declarados como '**private**' únicamente se puede acceder desde la clase que los definió.

Es decir, si a la propiedad `$comment` de la clase `publication` la definimos como `protected`, al hacer `fill()` y/o `get()` no debería haber problema

```
class publication extends model
{
    protected $comment;
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->fillable = ['comment'];
        $this->obtainable = ['comment'];
    }
}

$publication = new publication();
$publication->fill(["comment" => "This is my first comment"]);
print_r($publication->get());
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/faa4026a3d39ccd74509cab743ec5dd007de95bd)</kbd>

---

En respuesta a:

> ¿Hay alguna alternativa para poder acceder a las propiedades de las clases hijos desde los padres?

Puedes mantener tu código tal cual está y utilizar `public` o `private` para definir las propiedades en las clases hijas

Comment: Toda la razón, no me funcionaba con protected debido a que había otro fragmento de código que intervenía de mala forma. Muchas gracias por la respuesta, muy clara y detallada :)